# How To Prevent OutOfMemory Error before it occurs?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

How to prevent OutOfMemory Error before it occurs, and how to know if heap free space enough to add a new object to the list of objects.
here is my code, I want this add method to return false if adding the new person object will cause OutOfMemory Error.

```
private static List<Person> persons;
   
public boolean add(String id, String name) {

    boolean isExists = persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().isPresent();
   
    if (isExists == false){                  
         Person person = new Person(id,name);     
         persons.add(person);
         return true;            
    }

    return false;   
}
```

And this is person class:_

```
public class Person{

    private String id;
    private String name;

}
```

Comment: OutOfMemory is an error, not an exception in Java.

Comment: If adding such a tiny object is going to push you over the edge into out-of-memory, then I think you're already in trouble. you just don't know it.

Comment: @user14387228 it didn't case out-of-memory, but I have a task to implement a mechanism to prevent out-of-memory before it happened